# Select only when Condition is true - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, informatica

I have an ODS table and an Audit table.  I need to check the Audit table before deleting anything from the ODS table.  Right now, I'm doing it like this (below), however; that creates a nested loop in my execution plan.  I believe SQL server engine is checking the Audit table (WHERE clause) for every record.  Is there anyway to write this so the Audit table is only checked once and I can just do an Index Seek against my primary key without the nested loop?

I'm using this in an Informatica source qualifier.

```
SELECT
*Primary Key*
FROM
ODS_Table
WHERE
1 = (SELECT CASE WHEN 
      *Condition*
      THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      FROM AUDIT_TABLE)
```

Thanks!!

Comment: You could use a stored procedure for this kind of need, and just store the result coming from AUDIT_TABLE in a variable, no ?

Comment: This would definitely work but I need it to execute in one select statement.

Answer (score 1):

You could leverage a `JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT Primary Key
FROM ODS_Table
    JOIN AUDIT_TABLE ON *Condition*
```

This will ensure that rows from `ODS_Table` will *only return* if the meet the condition on the `AUDIT_TABLE`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I did give this a shot but it looks like the same execution plan.